# Harmon.ie for SharePoint Exception on Init - Registry Access

Tags: exception, registry, outlook-addin, securityexception, harmon.ie

I have a user who has successfully installed Harmon.ie to the computer, but the log file is showing an "Exception on Init" error.  The complete error is below:

```
Starting Harmonie
2015-01-16 06:48:57,172 INFO  [1] Mainsoft.Harmony.AddIn.HarmonyAddIn - OnConnection
2015-01-16 06:48:57,747 INFO  [1] Mainsoft.Harmony.AddIn.HarmonyAddIn - Load Harmonie version: 3.4.0.9975 Outlook Version 14.0.0.7105 X86 bit
2015-01-16 06:48:57,748 ERROR [1] Mainsoft.Harmony.AddIn.HarmonyAddIn - Exception on Init
System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
   at Mainsoft.Harmony.Utils.RedemptionCleaner.CleanOrphanRegistryKeys()
   at Mainsoft.Harmony.AddIn.HarmonyAddIn.Init()
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
```

Does anyone know the registry key that is trying to be accessed?

Comment: You need to contact the Harmony add-in developers. It looks like the issue comes from the add-in.

Comment: The Harmon.ie support site says to post here, and they will get in touch.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with a newly created empty add-in project? If not, this is a harmonie specific issue then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harmon.ie needs to access at the stage reported in the stack traces you have originally attached the following keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes

```
       "Redemption.Addin",            
        "Redemption.AddressLists",
        "Redemption.MAPIFolder",
        "Redemption.MAPITable",
        "Redemption.MAPIUtils",
        "Redemption.RDOSession",
        "Redemption.SafeAppointmentItem",
        "Redemption.SafeContactItem",
        "Redemption.SafeCurrentUser",
        "Redemption.SafeDistList",
        "Redemption.SafeInspector",
        "Redemption.SafeJournalItem",
        "Redemption.SafeMailItem",
        "Redemption.SafeMeetingItem",
        "Redemption.SafePostItem",
        "Redemption.SafeReportItem",
        "Redemption.SafeTaskItem", 
        "Mainsoft.Harmony.OutlookSidebar.TaskPaneSidebarAx"
```

Outlook should run under an account with sufficient privileges to read\write under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

By the way, you are running a quite old version of Harmon.ie, I suggest you download and install the latest 4.5 version from harmon.ie web site.

--- Jean

Comment: I answered my own question by using Process Monitor and filtering for Access Denied results, and it's the same result as Jean's.  The HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes location was where we were missing Write permissions.  Adding those has resolved the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates the user did not have sufficient permission to access this registry key.
Do you reproduce it when running Outlook as admin? (please try also to install as admin)

--- Jean

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Running Outlook as an administrator doesn't have the problem, and the add-in runs fine.  Uninstalling the add-in, and re-installing as an admin doesn't resolve the problem.  This user does not have administrator access, and we do not want them to.  We have already searched the registry for "Harmon.ie" and "Mainsoft" but we don't know which key permissions need to be updated to allow a non-administrator user to use the add-in, hence the question about which registry key(s) is/are causing the error listed above.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue with a newly created empty add-in project.